# Retrieve an image from a server location using Spring Boot to display in the front end

Tags: arrays, spring-boot

I'm trying to retrieve an image from a server location using Spring Boot to display in the front end.

I used a byte array conversion, but it takes a lot of time to retrieve. Is there any solution other than using `byte array`? Thank you!!!

```java
byte[] data;
imagepath = "E:\\images\\";
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imagePath));      
data= IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

Comment: other solution would be to give the file path to the client side and they will render the image however it involves a big risk as the client side must never be exposed to the server side file system

Comment: thanks Anas for your response. But our image folder is outside the tomcat in server I can't access by file path in client side and this byte array taking more time to retrive.

Comment: Is tomcat deployed on a different machine? If tomcat is on the same machine as the file then application running on tomcat is able to access the file